# How to change 24hr Time format

Tags: macos, time, clock

Is it possible to make the clock to show `0900` instead of `9:00` for 9AM? I’ve already tried changing the format under **System Preferences** → **Language & Region** → **Advanced…** but the setting doesn’t save.

Comment: What device, what OS?

Comment: @user3439894 - it has to be Mac, iOS doesn't have System Prefs, & OS is pretty much irrelevant, as it's never been possible.

Comment: The question as phrased originally didn't make it clear, so I added those bits.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done.

It looks like you can, but in fact it doesn't affect the menu bar clock.

System Prefs > Language & Region > Advanced... > Times

[image]

Changing the format in here, you'd expect it to affect the menu bar clock... but in fact it affects timestamps shown in Finder windows only.

[image]

There is no equivalent Advanced mode in Date & Time

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This requires the use of a third-party app such as [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/).

You can use the Time settings to set a custom menubar clock format: [image]

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Just in case you are using a Mac and you missed a step I made this picture on how to change the time format and well it did work for me

1. Click the time & date
2. Click the Preferences option
3. Click open language and region
4. Check or uncheck the time formate for 24 hours or not

Hope this helped 
[image]

Comment: This doesn't remove the colon in the menubar!

Comment: Now I understand , the examples where not there before , I thought he was talking about 24h to 12h Format ,I never perceived the colon in time format as being a problem ,sorry I couldn't Help